# Update View from ViewModel using Aspect Oriented Programming for read-only properties

Tags: wpf, mvvm, aop

I am using Aspect Oriented Programming in my WPF project. I have used it to decorate my viewModels with INotifyPropertyChanged interface and an implementation behavioral class as seen below:

```
Container.RegisterType<SomeViewModel>(
                new Interceptor<VirtualMethodInterceptor>(),
                new InterceptionBehavior(new LoggingBehavior(TraceEventType.Verbose)),
                new AdditionalInterface<INotifyPropertyChanged>(),
                new InterceptionBehavior<NotifyPropertyChangedBehavior>());
```

This works fine.
But when I have only get only properties like :

```
public bool IsDummy
        {
            get { return _isDummy; }
        }
```

How do I call the OnPropertyChanged method from the ViewModel, which does the job of updating the View(UI). So if I update variable _isDummy to true, I should be able to call something which does the same job as OnPropertyChanged("IsDummY");

Comment: what if you add private setter `private set { _isDummy = value; }` and update the property insteqad of backing field?

Comment: This makes sense to declare the setter as private. Thanks @Ash

Comment: @ASh  In hindsight I think if get part of a property gets me the updated value by calling some function e.g.,

    public bool IsDummy
    {
            get { return CheckIsStillDummy(); }
    }
    
In these kind of cases, it would not work with a private setter. So if the method CheckIsStillDummy() return me a different value, I wont be able to reflect it on the View.

Answer (score 0):

To notify the view that a value has changed you must raise the OnPropertyChanged event with the property which has changed. This is usually done by the standard implementation:

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Then in the setter of the property

```
public bool IsDummy
{
    set
    {
        if (_isDummy!= value)
        {
            _isDummy= value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

This syntax only works if it is called from within the property setter, alternatively you can call it when the property is changed elsewhere in the class

```
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsDummy));
```

Comment: The problem is with AOP, I have already decorated my ViewModels dynamically at runtime with INotifyPropertyChanged. So if there is a setter, no problems. But if its a read-only property then I can't call the OnPropertyChanged method since I don't have access to the method.